# Full posts on desktop, but excerpts on mobile

Tags: wordpress

I'm building a theme with some full posts on frontpage before the excerpts.
Now I'm trying to figure out, how to output only excerpts on mobile.

**Desktop**

- Full post
- Full post
- Excerpt
- Excerpt
- Excerpt

**Mobile**

- Excerpt
- Excerpt
- Excerpt
- Excerpt
- Excerpt

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`wp_is_mobile()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile) function:

```
if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {

    the_excerpt();

} else {

    the_content();

}
```

Comment: That's working pretty fine. Thank you for your time and your quick reply! I've never heard of this Conditional Tag before.